# Sequence with partial limits (0,1]

Tags: calculus, limits

I remember that in my calculus test there was a question about partial limits, which I didn't answer at the time because I didn't choose it at the test, and I still wonder what is the answer to it:

Is there a sequence which contains all the partial limits $$(0,1]$$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence
$$0,1,0,1/2,1,0,1/3,2/3,1,0,1/4,2/4,3/4,1,0,1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5,1,0,1/6,2/6,3/6,\dots.$$
Every real number in the interval $[0,1]$ is the limit of a subsequence of the above sequence.

**Remark:** We cannot get the half-open interval $(0,1]$ as the set of subsequential limits, For take $n$ very large. If $\frac{1}{n}$ is a limit point of an infinite subsequence, there are elements of the subsequence that are within $\frac{1}{2n}$ of $\frac{1}{n}$, so there are infinitely many elements of the sequence that are in the interval $(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{3}{2n})$. Thus $0$ is a limit point of the sequence.

Comment: My lecturer in Calculus called it "the bug sequence", and no, it doesn't answer my question because it has zero as a partial limit.

Comment: I have added a remark (with proof) that the set $(0,1]$ cannot be the set of subsequential limits. If you are familiar with closed sets, the argument of the remark can be much shortened.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works: Let $(x_n)$ be an enumeration for $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1]$. Then each $x\in (0,1]$ is a cluster point of $(x_n)$

Comment: I don't understand how does this work. Could you explain more?

Comment: @Catamorpihsm: Are you asking about a sequence which contain just $(0,1]$ as limit point? or any which contain all of them? For the former this is not possible and for the latter any enumeration of rational give us the desired sequence. Since $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1]$ is countable, there is an enumaration. Also the rationals are dense in $(0,1]$, so given a $x\in (0,1]$ we can define recursively  $n_0=0$ and $n_i = \min\{n>n_{i-1}: |x_n-x|<1/i\}$, then $(x_{n_i}) \to x$. Also notice that $0$ is a limit point.

Comment: Why isn't it possible?

Comment: @Catamorpihsm Check the remark of Andre